# Spark on AWS EMR cluster Master node 100% CPU utilization

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am using Apache-Spark on AWS-EMR Cluster (1 Master 4 Slaves - r4.xlarge instances).

My jobs are compiled and packaged as a jar in my Master node. Spark-submit is done from the master node referring to the local jar path in which the jobs are compiled. With Spark History Server, I find that the jobs are split across the data/task nodes for computation.

But after a certain point in time, the master node's CPU utilization peaks to 100% while the data node's CPU utilization are at 25-40%.
Even when no computation is done, my Master node's CPU utilization is around 40%.

In this link, [Spark History Server](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=687581) is discussed as a root cause. But clearing the application logs dint work for me.

1. Does placing the jar in master node cause the issue?
2. Should it be placed Distributed Cache?

Comment: How many partitions do you have? Can you show us the code and an indication of the stage where your master CPU starts peaking?

Comment: Hi, i was the solution giver in the link you provided, - i had this problem again as well, and another thing i did to solve it was to lynx into http://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-web-interfaces.html these admin pages, and i found that my hadoop fs had become corrupted, when i fixed the corruption, the cpu dropped from 100% to 20%, I have also disabled eventLog to false. sudo nano /etc/spark/conf.dist/spark-defaults.conf